# Pyramid server on vmware responds very slowly

Tags: python, webserver, debian, vmware, pyramid

First of all I'm new to Python and Pyramid framework.

I have:

- Win7 on my host
- Debian 6 on my vmware guest
- Python 2.6 on Debian machine
- Pyramid 1.3 on Debian machine

I created a virual environment using 'virualenvwrapper' and now I'm running 'Hello world' example from here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/firstapp.html#firstapp-chapter

The problem is that when I request http://localhost:8080/hello/world in Debian machine everything works fine. But when I request http://192.168.25.129:8080/hello/world from my host Win7 machine it takes 5-7 seconds to get response from server (192.168.25.129 thi is an vmware ip adress connected via NAT). I can not find the reason why it takes so much time.

I also installed 'apache2' on Debian machine to test request speed and found that apache respond takes 1 sec maximum. So is it a problem of Python or Pyramid? 
How can I reduce respond time of Pyramid server?

PS:sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `Pyramid` itself provides only debugging web server. It really very slow. For production you can use 'waitress' web server. It is much more faster.

Comment: Pyramid itself ships with no web server. Its scaffolds use waitress by default until you change it. :-)

Comment: @MichaelMerickel Pyramid tutorials suggests to use `wsgiref.simple_server` :)  and Serg said, that he used example from tutorial.

Comment: Ah I forgot about that silly tutorial, all the others use waitress. Yes, `wsgiref.simple_server` is in the python stdlib and is single-threaded and should never be used for anything past a demo.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the server to "waitress" and the speed of requests has increased dramatically!

Answer (score 1):

This problem probably has very little to do with python or pyramid and much more to do with the configuration of your virtual machine. If you really want to see what pyramid is doing you can turn on the performance profiler in the debug toolbar and find out where in the request things are taking a long time. If there is nothing slow in the pyramid side of the request, then you know it's before/after and you can look at the system setup, wsgi server and middleware.